# How hide file open security warning with my exe?

Tags: windows, qt, security, certificate, exe

My Qt exe displays windows file open security warning on startup.

Should I add something wrong in my app ?
Google told me to sign exe, but I checked Globalsign / Verisign, these certificate just replace unknown editor by my name. Warning is still here.

So how can delete this security popup ?

Of course, I mustn't change windows configuration. I must update my exe.

Thanks for help.

Comment: it seem that you should changed the `UAC` config in your IDE. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384691.aspx

Comment: What does the warning say?  Windows always warns the user when they run a downloaded executable, there's nothing you can do about that.  Although if you distribute an installer rather than the executable itself, only the installer will generate the warning.

Comment: You've right, i've downloaded it from my compilator box. I've no problem when i copy it from my installer. Thanks.